# ng-repeat inside ng-repeat and other ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've got the following json data returned from a service request:

```
[
  {
    "order": 1,
    "service": "DCS 2.X",
    "titulos": {
      "titulo0": "NEW BACKEND VLAN",
      "subtitulos0": {
        "sub1": "1.1New or update Landscape (backend & frontend from TC)"
      },
      "titulo2": "NEW SYSTEM (VIRTUAL MACHINE OR BUILDING BLOCK)",
      "subtitulos2": {},
      "titulo3": "INCREASE OR DRECREASE OF SLICES",
      "subtitulos3": {
        "sub4": "3.1SOM@SAP order"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "order": 2,
    "service": "DCS 3",
    "titulos": {
      "titulo5": "INCREASE OR DRECREASE OF SLICES",
      "subtitulos5": {
        "sub6": "3.1SOM@SAP order"
      },
      "titulo7": "UPDATE OF AN OPERATING SYSTEM (NOT MAIN RELEASE)",
      "subtitulos7": {
        "sub8": "5.1Change Request (no SOM@SAP order)"
      },
      "titulo9": "DEDICATED CUSTER",
      "subtitulos9": {}
    }
  }
]
```

I want to show with three ng-repeat, something like this

```
order 1 service DCS 2.X
     NEW BACKEND VLAN
              1.1New or update Landscape (backend & frontend from TC)
     NEW SYSTEM (VIRTUAL MACHINE OR BUILDING BLOCK)
     INCREASE OR DRECREASE OF SLICES
              3.1SOM@SAP order
order 2 service DCS 3
     INCREASE OR DRECREASE OF SLICES
              3.1SOM@SAP order
     UPDATE OF AN OPERATING SYSTEM (NOT MAIN RELEASE)
              5.1Change Request (no SOM@SAP order)
     DEDICATED CUSTER
```

I made this:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in orders" class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">Order #{{item.order}} - {{item.service}}</div>
    <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in item.titulos" >
        <div style="font-weight: bold;">{{value}}</div>
        <hr class="track" />
        <div ng-repeat="(key2, value2) in value" >
            {{key2}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But gives me the following error:

```
Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Use 'track by' expression to specify unique keys. Repeater: (key2, value2) in value, Duplicate key: string:D, Duplicate value: D
```

if I use track by.. dont works either.. If you can help me, or give a better idea for this

There may be 10 orders or more.. Thanks

Comment: just add track by $index in all of your ng-repeats

Comment: your json is wrong titulos must be an array but is an object same for subtiulos, fix json, and not necesarry  change name of atrtributes with index.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div ng-repeat="n in [42, 42, 43, 43] track by $index">
  {{n}}
</div>
```

Add track by index to the loops

[docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#tracking-and-duplicates](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#tracking-and-duplicates)

Comment: dont works fine, it looks like this: https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-gNor0id2UMA/WYt8NPb5rjI/AAAAAAAADhA/Ul4tO-OAHbM-urfxDEah60ZI_72j5U5KwCL0BGAYYCw/h610/2017-08-09.png

Answer (score 0):

The json you provide is malformed, to work with multiple ng-repeat... if that json is privded for an api the way you need to access will be diferent to this example i fix the json to improve and work with the ng-repeats.

**HTML**

```
 <div ng-repeat="item in orders track by $index" class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">Order #{{item.order}} - {{item.service}}</div>
    <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in item.titulos track by $index" >
        <div style="font-weight: bold;">{{value}}</div>
        <hr class="track" />
        <div ng-repeat="(key2, value2) in value track by $index" >
            {{key2}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JSON FIX**

```
$scope.orders=[
  {
    "order": 1,
    "service": "DCS 2.X",
    "titulos": [
      {
      "titulo": "NEW BACKEND VLAN",
      "subtitulos": [{
        "titulo": "1.1New or update Landscape (backend & frontend from TC)"
      }],
      },
      {
      "titulo": "NEW SYSTEM (VIRTUAL MACHINE OR BUILDING BLOCK)",
      "subtitulos":[]
      },
      {"titulo": "INCREASE OR DRECREASE OF SLICES",
      "subtitulos": [{
        "titulo": "3.1SOM@SAP order"
      }]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "order": 2,
    "service": "DCS 3",
    "titulos": [{
      "titulo": "INCREASE OR DRECREASE OF SLICES",
      "subtitulos": [{
        "titulo": "3.1SOM@SAP order"
      }]
      },
      {
      "titulo": "UPDATE OF AN OPERATING SYSTEM (NOT MAIN RELEASE)",
      "subtitulos": [{
        "titulo": "5.1Change Request (no SOM@SAP order)"
      }]
      },
      {
      "titulo": "DEDICATED CUSTER",
      "subtitulos": []
    }]
  }
]
```